# Andengine AnimatedSprite is losing 1 second later

Tags: android, sprite, delayed-job, andengine

i created a animatedsprite in andengine codes below.I wanna lose it 1 second later.How can i do that?

```
 public void fireBullet4() {

    float startXC=player.getX()+10;

    float startYC=player.getY()-70;


    bullet4=new AnimatedSprite(startXC, startYC, HelicopterActivity.this.bulletTextureRegion4);



    scene.attachChild(bullet4);
```

}

Comment: What does you mean by 'lose it'? Remove the sprite completely, change duration, something else perhaps...? Also, it would be good if you could provide any code you've tried already.

Comment: I wanna remove the sprite completely 1 second later.

Answer (score 1):

The logic to remove a `Sprite` safely is pretty staightforward and illustrated by one of the [AndEngine examples](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/SpriteRemoveExample.java). Just make sure you do the removing on the `UpdateThread`:

```
this.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        /* Now it is save to remove the entity! */
        pScene.detachChild(SpriteRemoveExample.this.mFaceToRemove);
    }
});
```

As far as I can tell, there is no build-in option to automatically remove the `Sprite` again after a certain delay. However, you should be able to create a [`TimerHandler`](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/engine/handler/timer/TimerHandler.java) with a callback and wait for the one-second-tick to happen to remove the `Sprite`.